# Phalcon\Text camelize/uncamelize usage

Tags: phalcon

I am having an issue with camelize/uncamelize (`\Phalcon\Text`)

My understanding is that this function creates camel case strings like [`ucwords()`](http://php.net/ucwords) or [`ucfirst()`](http://php.net/ucfirst)

The following tests reveal: This test passes:

**camelize:**

- nice -> Nice
- nice weather -> NiceWeather (Not sure if this should be like that. The space is stripped out. If this is the intended behavior then we need to add it to the docs)
- nice_weather -> NiceWeather (Why does the underscore disappear? If this is the intended behavior then we need to add it to the docs)
- nIcE -> Nice

**uncamelize:**

- Nice -> nice
- Nice Weather -> nice weather
- Nice_Weather -> nice_weather
- NIcE -> nic_e  (the capital letter switches to underscore)

Comment: Mod note: Phalcon is in the process of moving many frequently asked questions from Google Groups over to SO. Please don't be alarmed with the number of questions Nikolaos asks and self-answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camelize/uncamelize methods are intended to convert strings with underscores to camel case ones. Specifically, these methods are used by `Phalcon\Model` to convert table names to their respective classes and vice versa. Thus, we can get the name of a table from the class name.

Reference:
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/4.0/api/Phalcon_Text.html

For Phalcon v5.0 the `Phalcon\Text` class has been removed and replaced with the `Phalcon\Support\HelperFactory`. The factory is registered in the DI container with the name `helper`.

```
$helper = new Phalcon\Support\HelperFactory();
$result = $helper->camelize('CocoBongo'); //coco_bongo
```

One can also instantiate the `Phalcon\Support\Helper\Camelize` class directly

```
$camelize = Phalcon\Support\Helper\Camelize();
$result   = $camelize('CocoBongo'); // coco_bongo
```

The same applies to `uncamelize`

Answer (score 0):

Reference: http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Text.html

Hi, we need to change the example of uncamelize:

0.4.x:

```
- <?php Phalcon_Text::camelize('CocoBongo'); //coco_bongo
+ <?php Phalcon_Text::uncamelize('CocoBongo'); //coco_bongo
```

0.5.x:

```
- <?php Phalcon\Text::camelize('CocoBongo'); //coco_bongo
+ <?php Phalcon\Text::uncamelize('CocoBongo'); //coco_bongo
```